# upgarding grails 1.1.1 to 1.2.1

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to upgrade my grails project from grails 1.1.1 to grails 1.2.1.
when I am trying to run my application I am getting below error message:

```
 I am using java 1.7._09 and GGTS 3.6.4.
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
    when I am trying to add tomcat 1.2.1 in my application.properties file I am getting below error:
```

My GGTS is using default groovy compiler 2.3. Should I need to change the groovy complier?

I have searched in Google but I didn't understand:
[search result from google](http://how-to-fix-incompatibleclasschangeerror-for-your-groovy-projects-running-on-jdk7)

```
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:155)
    at gant.Gant.processTargets(Gant.groovy:480)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:485)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:301)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:240)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: addChild:  Child name 'grails-errorhandler' is not unique
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:781)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addChild(StandardContext.java:2128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:925)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:193)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1140)
    ... 438 more
startup.ContextConfig Occurred at line 7 column 422
startup.ContextConfig Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
core.StandardContext Error getConfigured
core.StandardContext Context [/BASF_bdw] startup failed due to previous errors
Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/BASF_bdw
plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager Started to scan for plugin changes in every 5000ms.
```

I have found duplicate servlet name in .grails/***/resource/web.xml while running the run-app command in GGTS.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>grails-errorhandler</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>grails-errorhandler</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

may I know why it is generating duplicate servlet name and how to fix this ?

Comment: Google search result : http://blog.proxerd.pl/article/how-to-fix-incompatibleclasschangeerror-for-your-groovy-projects-running-on-jdk7

Comment: you just invented the time machine!

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

The blog says that you should search for every class that extends the class Exception or a subclass of it and convert it from a groovy to a java class. However, it looks like it is not your code, but the internal Grails code that throws the exception.

Looking at your previous questions, it seems your final goal is to make your war runnable in a Java 7 Environment.
You should stick to java 6 on your upgrade-journey until you hit a Grails version that just runs on Java 7. 
After every successful upgrade, compile your project with Java 6 and try to run it in a servlet container that runs on Java 7. Perhaps you'r lucky and it just works.

I'm pretty sure that this will not the last problem.
I don't know how many lines of code your project has, perhaps it's an option to reimplement the whole project in grails 3.

Comment: when I tried to change java version to 1.6, I am getting below "Unsupported major. minor version 51.0". I have changed the complier from 1.7 to 1.6 in both system variable and GGTS properties.
One more strange thing is I have change the tomcat version 2.1.1 to 1.2.1 then I am getting "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: addChild:  Child name 'grails-errorhandler' is not unique". I have checked the web.xml file in .grails folder and found two servlet with same name 'grails-errorhandler'. why it is generating duplicate while running the application and how to fix this?

Comment: That's the pain of upgrading. I'm not old enough to have experience with  an upgrade to 1.2 :). Some hints I can give you: If the errors getting to wired, try `grails clean`. Sometimes it was necessary to delete or better, backup cache dirs. Read and follow the upgrade notes http://docs.grails.org/1.3.9/guide/2.%20Getting%20Started.html#2.2%20Upgrading%20from%20previous%20versions%20of%20Grails . Create a new Grails project with the new Grails version and compare the application.properties, Config.groovy and BuildConfig.groovy settings. Try `grails upgrade`.

Comment: Please don't edit the content of the original question from your previous problem to the next one. While I don't think that this question will help anyone in the year 2017, someone with the same problem of the new question and will not see the relation with answers about the previous topic. I was wrong anyway. The source of the error was that the version of the tomcat plugin was not the same as the version of Grails. I forgot that it worked that way with older Grails releases.